# How do I use the AD username to select content from a WSS list

Tags: active-directory, wss

I have a WSS list containing user profile data (Columns: Username, Name, DOB) etc. I need to display the correct user profile from this list using the username of the currently logged in user (Active Directory).

I know the WSS web parts are limited so I'm going to use the RSS feed for the list and filter & transform it through some XSL using the XML web part.

How do I get the username of the currently logged in user and stick it into my XSL?

Comment: Your question sounds like you are going to do something awkward. Can you explain the reason why you need this, so we could find a better solution for your problem?

Comment: Simply this: display a users profile on a WSS site. The profile was maintained in a php-based wiki and now a move is being made to WSS. Maintaining user info in a list seemed to be the easiest option as opposed to creating a separate site for each user (approx 200 people)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint already has an out of the boxy user profile list, which it uses internally to store user data. When you use MOSS, the user data is stored in the sites Shared Service Provider, and a service (timerjob) updates all user info in sites using that SSP.

To store more profile info than WSS does out of the box i suggest you create a new list, that has a person / group field in it. But most info like emailadress etc are already in that (hidden) list.

More info on the hidden user list and talking to it through code [here](http://www.zimmergren.net/archive/2008/06/25/sharepoints-hidden-user-list-user-information-list.aspx).
More info on using the current user in webparts [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/joshuag/archive/2008/06/03/getting-the-current-user-name-or-id-in-sharepoint-using-sharepoint-designer-no-code.aspx).

P.S. I suggest looking into the webpart used in the 2nd article, the DataFormWebPart. It is the most versatile webpart out there, that can be bound to any datasource and can be styled using Xsl.

Comment: Thanks for your help Colin. I found this (http://sharepointjavascript.wordpress.com/2009/09/20/accessing-user-profile-information-in-wss-3-0-with-javascript) which is exactly what I needed for the broader task.